# How to convert string to date format in R

Tags: r, string, datetime, lubridate

I have a column of strings in the following format:

```
Wed, 6 Dec 2000 08:47:00 -0800 (PST)
```

How can I convert this into date format using lubridate or another package? I have done this before, but there was no `-0800 (PST)` at the end.

Thank you.

Comment: Use the function as.Date()

Comment: `as.POSIXct(x, format="%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z", tz="US/Pacific")` - see `?strptime` - *‘%z’ Signed offset in hours and minutes from UTC, so ‘-0800’ is 8 hours behind UTC.*

Comment: Thank you so much @thelatemail. However my data has 500,000 rows. So isn't strptime a bit slow for that. I will use lubridate parse_date_time. I found that to be very fast.

Comment: @ilyas - `as.POSIXct` in my testing is **much** faster than `parse_date_time` - by the order of about 3 times faster.

Comment: Oh OK. I think I had compared it to strptime .Also, where can I find the full list of zone names? The one which is assigned to tz?

Comment: @ilyas - `strptime` is even faster again. Also, see `OlsonNames()`

Comment: OK, I tested it and you are right. However extracting info from datetime column such as weekday is faster using lubridate or data.table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get a result using `strptime()` without even worrying about the timezone name at the end:

```
> x - "Wed, 6 Dec 2000 08:47:00 -0800 (PST)"
> strptime(x,  "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
[1] "2000-12-07 00:47:00"
```

However, if you want to remove the timezone name, you can use `substr()` to do this:

```
> strptime(substr(x, 1, nchar(x)-6),  "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
[1] "2000-12-07 00:47:00"
```

Comment: Thank you. I will use parse_date_time(x = info[,Date], orders = 'a, d b Y H:M:S z', tz="US/Pacific").

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `parse_date_time`

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(x, "adbY HMS z", tz = "US/Pacific")
#[1] "2000-12-06 08:47:00 PST"
```